# ExtJS4 Model.save() error: record is undefined.

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, model, extjs4

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm making an app with ExtJS 4 using the MVC architecture. I have a Model (User) with the proxy, a store (Users), and a Controller.

The controller listens for a button to "Add User", which receives data from a form.
I create a new User and pass in the data:

```
var newUser = new MY.model.User({name: textInputValue}); //bob
```

and then call

```
newUser.save({
    success: function() { ... },
    failure: function() { ... }
});
```

### What is happening:

Whether I use the callbacks or not, and even if the save() function params are empty, I get the following error:

```
record is undefined:
me.set(record.data);
```

Thrown in .../ext-4.0.1/src/data/Model.js on line 972.

### What I've been able to find out so far:

Running stack traces shows that:

```
operation = Ext.create('Ext.data.Operation', options);
```

on line 968 (of the same Model.js file mentioned above) returns an object that has records, of which has the data that I'm passing it.

**Two questions here:**

1. Is this a bug?
2. Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're a life saver. I hope they sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd suggest that you [upgrade to the latest version 4.0.2a](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/), so you got the latest bug fixes.

Ext JS has its own class system, so you cannot instantiate an Ext based class with `new` keyword. Always use `Ext.create` to instantiate a new class from Ext JS and only use `new` for plain prototype based classes.

For models you can create a new instance through the model manager:

```
var user = Ext.ModelManager.create({
    name : 'Bob'
}, 'User');
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

I've changed my class instantiation method to the one you described above and then tested, then I upgraded the framework and tested again; the issue persists.

The lines I mentioned above for v4.0.1 are now 1013 and 1006 respectively in v4.0.2a.

I'll try and tinker with Model.js for a bit to see if perhaps it's a bug.

Comment: Not a bug, just a dumb half implemented mistake.  

I need to return the completed User object along with the success message from the server's JSON output.